# Tensorflow failed to use gpu: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.396.26 not found

Tags: tensorflow

I need helping on setting up tensorflow with GPU, however got error while trigging tensorflow job with gpu:

```
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.396.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already have nvidia driver verison 396, cuda tool kit 9 and cudnn7 installed. and my gpu is Tesla K80. i checked files under /usr/lib/nvidia-396, only libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.396.24 found.

Can anyone help me out?

Best,
Juhua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that 2 nvidia drivers versions are conflicting `396.24` and `396.26`

When you update the drivers, the corresponding cuda library is not always updated.

You can reinstall libcuda

```
sudo apt-get purge libcuda1-*
sudo apt-get install libcuda1-396
```

Comment: Thanks Piercus for your answer. It was caused incompatible lib version. I fixed it by forcing to remove all related libs and reinstall about